# Lose script when changing component angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I downloaded a HTML / CSS template for my project, then I created an Angular project and put all the script files in the assets folder, I call them on **angular.json** like this:

```
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "src/assets/css/plugins.css",
          "src/assets/css/style.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "src/assets/js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/plugins.js",
          "src/assets/js/infobox.js",
          "src/assets/js/custom.js"
        ]
```

But when I change component I lose these scripts (it looks like I haven't called them yet) but when I refresh the page they work.
I don't have the reason.
any ideas or solutions?

Comment: That might be a dumb answer... but did you close the ng server and run again?

Comment: yes, i do this several times.
but do you think that  problem in the script files itself? because they are written by jquery and I have not read it

Comment: Might be... It already happened to me but I restarted the service and it worked... try to take a look on these scripts documentation, it must have something you're probably missing

Comment: @EduardoRosostolato ok i will do , thanks for your answer :)